# Is it possible to create duplicate wordpress site by a new user?

Tags: wordpress

im stacked with the question. Example, i have wordpress site at domain name site.com. I wanna to new users, after registration users can create duplicate of main site with replace prebuilt variable. Duplicate version must have view like site.com/nickname-of-user.

**Main question**: how i can make this with easily way? Maybe exist a ready solution. Maybe most effective use another cms?

This is a lot of function, that should be in a site. Example, affilate program for users registration, paid access for this site, etc.

Which cms is better for this tasks? Thank you for ur answers

Answer (score 0):

Users can create new sites using sub-directories using WordPress Multisite (https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/)

There is also a plugin called BlogTemplates (https://github.com/wpmudev/blogtemplates) that would allow your users to create a clone of a site upon sign up. It is not being maintained but it is still functional.